# Insert Arabic text into MySQL data-base -PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my Android app. I need to update on data-base directly, so I need php code to receive a JSON object. However, I attempt to insert Arabic values into MySql database field; but for an unknown reason it inserts into database when it is a non-Arabic text, the insertion is not executed if it is Arabic text

The **PHP** code as below; as noted the value that needed to insert in ArabicText variable:

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("dbdemo",$link);
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
mysql_query("set CHARACTER set 'utf8'",$link);
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$ArabicText="إدخال جرد للأصناف";
$query=mysql_query("insert into voucher values('000001','17','','$ArabicText','20140101','NIS','1.000000','35.0','0.0','0.0','2','0','0','','9','0','0','','','','1','20140101','','110101','0.0','')");
```

Is there any problem on it? **or** is there any additional things needed? 
I attempt really many solutions which all related to add "utf8" but it does not work with me!

any help will be appreciated,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read Arabic from mysql through php

1) The field containing the Arabic text should have Charset utf8 collation utf8_unicode_ci

2) In the page where you want to read this field:

a)set the charset of the page to windows-1256

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
```

b) After establishing the connection to the MySQL write this two lines

mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1256");

mysql_query("set characer set cp1256");

I hope that it works well with you.

Answer (score 1):

Please alter the database and set the collation to the database as utf8 utf8-unicode-ci

Comment: what does that mean please? ... how can do this?

Comment: just go to mysql workbench , right click on your database and select 'Alter Schema' option in that you can set collation and apply the changes

Comment: yes ,, really thanks @Yograj Sudewad but unfortunately I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: @Maheera Jazi Please set the same collation to the table also(for this alter the table as same as previous comment procedure)

Comment: yes thanks really @Yograj Sudewad. Just as you see from above answer  I just add these two lines 'mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1256");'
'mysql_query("set characer set cp1256");' and everything goes well with me! ...

Answer (score 0):

use `utf8_general_ci` Collation for table field